# How to create new columns from one

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("google?????amazom", "google?????amazon?????yahoo", "yahoo"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

using the separated option of text column ????? I would like to create a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), google = c(1,1,0), amazon = c(1,1,0), yahoo = c(0,0,1))
```

How is it possible to make it?

Comment: In the input you had `amazom` instead of `amazon` in one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` to split the 'text' column with `sep` as one or more question marks, then create a column of 1s ('ind') and pivot to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(text, sep="\\?+") %>%
   mutate(ind = 1) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = text, values_from = ind, values_fill = list(ind = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id google amazon yahoo
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1      1      1     0
#2     2      1      1     1
#3     3      0      0     1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `strsplit` and `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$text, "?????", fixed = TRUE), df$id))[2:1])
# values
#ind amazon google yahoo
#  1      1      1     0
#  2      1      1     1
#  3      0      0     1
```

Comment: is it possible to make the second option a dataframe? Why are you using [2:1]? Thank you very much it is the right option

Comment: @Nathalie Yes, you can do `as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(..`. The `2:1` is to rearrange the columns order from `stack`. If I do the `table` wihtout that, the results will be in the transposed format